# Spring webflux WebTestClient with query parameter

Tags: java, testing, spring-webflux

In my webflux application, i have this `GET` endpoint

```
v3/callback?state=cGF5bWVudGlkPTRiMmZlMG
```

I am trying to write  an integration test using `WebTestClient`

```
@Test
public void happyScenario() {
    webTestClient.get().uri("/v3/callback?state=cGF5bWVudGlkPTRiMmZlMG")
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus()
            .isOk();
}
```

This test case return `404 notFound`, if i removed the query parameter it will be called but the `state` parameter it will be missing

I tried to use `attribute`

```
  webTestClient.get().uri("/v3/callback")
            .attribute("state","cGF5bWVudGlkPTRiMmZlMG")
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus()
            .isOk();
```

but still the `state` parameter is missing, How can i include a query parameter with request when using `webTestClient` ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can make use of `UriBuilder`.

```java
webTestClient.get()
            .uri(uriBuilder ->
                    uriBuilder
                            .path("/v3/callback")
                            .queryParam("state", "cGF5bWVudGlkPTRiMmZlMG")
                            .build())
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus()
            .isOk();
```

This should work.

Answer (score 3):

If your query parameter value contains curly braces, for example like this:

```java
webTestClient.get()
    .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
        .path("/v3/callback")
        .queryParam("query", "{ some { GraphQL { query } } }")
        .build())
    .exchange()
    .expectStatus()
    .isOk();
```

Then `UriBuilder` will attempt to do variable substitution on the contents of the curly braces and you will likely get an exception on the `build()` call. In order to avoid it, place your request parameters in a separate `requestParams` map and use controlled variable substitution by calling `build(requestParams)` when building the `URI`:

```java
var requestParams = Map.of(
    "query", "{ some { GraphQL { query } } }"
);

webTestClient.get()
    .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
        .path("/v3/callback")
        .queryParam("query", "{query}")
        .build(requestParams))
    .exchange()
    .expectStatus()
    .isOk();
```

Another tip. If you find `.uri(uriBuilder -> ...)` syntax a bit complex, you can prepare the `URI` explicitly before the request:

```java
var requestParams = Map.of(
    "query", "{ some { GraphQL { query } } }"
);

URI uri = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory("/v3/callback")
    .builder()
    .queryParam("query", "{query}")
    .build(requestParams);

webTestClient.get()
    .uri(uri)
    .exchange()
    .expectStatus()
    .isOk();
```

If the `URI` is prepared beforehand - it is easier to check the generated `URI` in the debugger or log it.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the Kotlin Sample for the above

```
val requestParams = LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>()
requestParams.add("A", "abc")      
requestParams.add("B", "def")       
requestParams.add("C", "ghi")
 
val uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("/v3/callback").queryParams(requestParams).build().toUri()   

webTestClient.get().uri{uri}.exchange().expectStatus().isOk
```